# Embed View Only Word Document in Webpage

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

Working a on a Google Web Toolkit project. I want to show a word document in a webpage. Does not have to be the MS Word 2007 view. Any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't display a Work document in a webpage without using some kind of ActiveX plugin. And that solution would work only for your clients that use IE on Windows...

Comment: How would I combine an ActiveX plugin with a GWT project? The reqs of IE on windows is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use RPC; whereby you send the Word Document to the server first, upon which, it would be converted into HTML and sent back to the Client. You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227236/convert-word-doc-to-html-programmatically-in-java) question to know how to convert the word document into HTML.