# Converting doc file to docx file format

Tags: java

I have converted docx file to html since its a Zipped format. but i have to convert the doc files too.Is there any way to change the doc file to docx file through code(prefer java).Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using [APACHE POI](http://poi.apache.org/)

It will provide you functionality to get data from DOC file and you can directly operate on it without converting it to DOCX.

And to convert DOC file to HTML look at this: [convert-word-doc-to-html-programmatically-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227236/convert-word-doc-to-html-programmatically-in-java)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [wv library](http://wvware.sourceforge.net/) for decoding the Microsoft .doc format