# Convert DOC file to DOCX with Java

Tags: java, ms-office, docx, doc

I need to use DOCX files (actually the XML contained in them) in a Java software I'm currently developing, but some people in my company still use the DOC format.

Do you know if there is a way to convert a DOC file to the DOCX format using Java ? I know it's possible using C#, but that's not an option

I googled it, but nothing came up...

Thanks

Comment: [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) could might help you with this task..

Answer (score 3):

You may try [Aspose.Words for Java](http://www.aspose.com/categories/java-components/aspose.words-for-java/default.aspx). It allows you to [load a DOC file](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/java-components/aspose.words-for-java/load-or-create-a-document.html) and [save it as DOCX format](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/java-components/aspose.words-for-java/save-a-document.html). The code is very simple as shown below:

```
// Open a document.  
Document doc = new Document("input.doc"); 
// Save document. 
doc.save("output.docx");
```

Please see if this helps in your scenario.

Disclosure: I work as developer evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Document doc = new Document(“MyDir” + “in.doc”);
while using the above code in my java page, it shows “The constructor Document(String) is undefined”

and using this code ------------> doc.save(“output.docx”); it shows like “The method save(String) is undefined for the type Document”

Whether i have to import any jar file. If means, please list out the jar file

Comment: how can I try this? which dependency I need to use?

Comment: @Rajesh, please [download & add Aspose.Words for Java](https://downloads.aspose.com/words/java) library in your project to be able to convert DOC to DOCX and many [other formats](https://docs.aspose.com/words/java/supported-document-formats/) using Java. You can also use Aspose.Words for Java directly from a [Maven](https://repository.aspose.com/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/repo/com/aspose/aspose-words) based project. For any more details, please refer to [Documentation](https://docs.aspose.com/words/java/system-requirements/). Disclosure: I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [JODConverter](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter) to see if it fits the bill.  I haven't personally used it.

Comment: It apparently can convert MSOffice files to OpenOffice format, but not DOC to DOCX. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

Use newer versions of jars `jodconverter-core-4.2.2.jar` and `jodconverter-local-4.2.2.jar`

```
String inputFile = "*.doc";
String outputFile = "*.docx";

LocalOfficeManager localOfficeManager = LocalOfficeManager.builder()
            .install()
            .officeHome(getDefaultOfficeHome()) //your path to openoffice
            .build();

  try {
      localOfficeManager.start();
      final DocumentFormat format
              = DocumentFormat.builder()
                      .from(DefaultDocumentFormatRegistry.DOCX)
                      .build();

      LocalConverter
              .make()
              .convert(new FileInputStream(new File(inputFile)))
              .as(DefaultDocumentFormatRegistry.getFormatByMediaType("application/msword"))
              .to(new File(outputFile))
              .as(format)
              .execute();

  } catch (OfficeException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  } finally {
      OfficeUtils.stopQuietly(localOfficeManager);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

JODConvertor calls OpenOffice/LibreOffice via a network protocol. It can therefore 'do anything you can do in OpenOffice'. This includes converting formats. But it only does as good a job as whatever version of OpenOffice you are running. I have some art in one of my docs, and it doesn't convert them as I hoped.

JODConvertor is no longer supported, according to the google code web site for v3.

To get JOD to do the job you need to do something like

```
private static void transformBinaryWordDocToDocX(File in, File out)
{
    OfficeDocumentConverter converter = new OfficeDocumentConverter(officeManager);
    DocumentFormat docx = converter.getFormatRegistry().getFormatByExtension("docx");
    docx.setStoreProperties(DocumentFamily.TEXT,
    Collections.singletonMap("FilterName", "MS Word 2007 XML"));

    converter.convert(in, out, docx);
}


private static void transformBinaryWordDocToW2003Xml(File in, File out)
{
    OfficeDocumentConverter converter = new OfficeDocumentConverter(officeManager);;
    DocumentFormat w2003xml = new DocumentFormat("Microsoft Word 2003 XML", "xml", "text/xml");
    w2003xml.setInputFamily(DocumentFamily.TEXT);
    w2003xml.setStoreProperties(DocumentFamily.TEXT, Collections.singletonMap("FilterName", "MS Word 2003 XML"));
    converter.convert(in, out, w2003xml);
}



private static OfficeManager officeManager;

@BeforeClass
public static void setupStatic() throws IOException {

          /*officeManager = new DefaultOfficeManagerConfiguration()
      .setOfficeHome("C:/Program Files/LibreOffice 3.6")
      .buildOfficeManager();
      */

    officeManager = new ExternalOfficeManagerConfiguration().setConnectOnStart(true).setPortNumber(8100).buildOfficeManager();


    officeManager.start();
}

@AfterClass
public static void shutdownStatic() throws IOException {

    officeManager.stop();
}
```

For this to work you need to be running LibreOffice as a networked server ( I could not get the 'run on demand' part of JODConvertor to work under windows with LO 3.6 very well )

Comment: does this code convert DOC to DOCX using OO on headless mode ?

Answer (score 0):

I needed the same conversion ,after researching a lot found Jodconvertor can be useful in it , you can download the jar from 
https://code.google.com/p/jodconverter/downloads/list

Add jodconverter-core-3.0-beta-4-sources.jar file to your project lib

```
  //1) Create OfficeManger Object     
OfficeManager officeManager = new DefaultOfficeManagerConfiguration()
                .setOfficeHome(new File("/opt/libreoffice4.4"))
                .buildOfficeManager();
        officeManager.start();
    // 2) Create JODConverter converter   
        OfficeDocumentConverter converter = new OfficeDocumentConverter(
                officeManager);
// 3)Create DocumentFormat for docx
DocumentFormat docx = converter.getFormatRegistry().getFormatByExtension("docx");
        docx.setStoreProperties(DocumentFamily.TEXT,
                Collections.singletonMap("FilterName", "MS Word 2007 XML"));
//4)Call convert funtion in converter object
converter.convert(new File("doc/AdvancedTable.doc"), new File(
                "docx/AdvancedTable.docx"), docx);
```

Answer (score -1):

To convert DOC file to HTML look at this
([Convert Word doc to HTML programmatically in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227236/convert-word-doc-to-html-programmatically-in-java))

Use this: http://poi.apache.org/

Or use this :

```
XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.openOrCreate(new File("hello.docx")));  
XWPFWordExtractor wx = new XWPFWordExtractor(docx);  
String text = wx.getText();  
System.out.println("text = "+text);
```

Comment: `if (DOCX != HTML && hasNoOtherAnswer()) doDownvote()` - OK, you mentioned poi, no -1 from me.

Comment: t will provide you functionality to get data from DOC file and you can directly operate on it without converting it to DOCX.

Comment: *I need to use DOCX files*. There is a strong requirement, most likely because the software already can process DOCX but some input is still the old DOC format. So converting to HTML and adding a html parser doesn't look like an option

Comment: Indeed... All my parsers are already set up for the DOCX format (with the Open XML behind). I do not have time to write the parsers for HTML or text file, hence my question

Answer (score -3):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import com.lowagie.text.Document;
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;
import com.lowagie.text.Paragraph;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;


import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.WordExtractor;

import org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.Range;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;


public class TestCon {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        POIFSFileSystem fs = null;  
        Document document = new Document();

        try {  
            System.out.println("Starting the test");  
            fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream("C:/Users/312845/Desktop/a.doc"));  

            HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);  
            WordExtractor we = new WordExtractor(doc);  

            OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/Users/312845/Desktop/test.docx")); 

            System.out.println("Document testing completed");  
        } catch (Exception e) {  
            System.out.println("Exception during test");  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        } finally {  
            // close the document  
            document.close();  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not well accepted here. Please explain him what you did and how it answers his question.