# How to download .docx file from url and save as .doc on Android

Tags: android, docx, doc

I need to download file .docx from url and save it as .doc on external memory on android. I didn't find the way. Can anyone give example of that.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to do it without any modification to the file, because `.docx` and `.doc` has different structure.

In this way you will need to process the file by yourself on the Android device.
In this way you may find helpful the [Apache POI library for Java](http://poi.apache.org/) for working with Microsoft Documents.

[Apache POI - HWPF and XWPF - Java API to Handle Microsoft Word Files](http://poi.apache.org/document/index.html)

Comment: That library is heavy and it works only for doc in android , not for docx documents, but thanks. Now I am trying to find convertor from docx to doc. Any sugestion?

Comment: @Mikky http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664728/convert-doc-file-to-docx-with-java