# how to read the formated text as a html text from ms word(.doc) using poi?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to read the formated text as a html text like(<html><b>boldvalue<b><img src"link" ></html>) also i want to get the image using the image tag link. I'm using poi does poi have any option to get data like this in html format?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868713/convert-word-to-html-with-apache-poi - duplicate

Comment: than how can i get image from the image tag

Comment: The image tags are comes with comment line also css are comes in a class but i want the css with in the tag like <table width="80%" style="something" >. how to get this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
HWPFDocumentCore wordDocument = WordToHtmlUtils.loadDoc(new FileInputStream("D:\\temp\\seo\\1.doc"));

        WordToHtmlConverter wordToHtmlConverter = new WordToHtmlConverter(
                DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder()
                        .newDocument());
        wordToHtmlConverter.processDocument(wordDocument);
        Document htmlDocument = wordToHtmlConverter.getDocument();
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(htmlDocument);
        StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(out);

        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer serializer = tf.newTransformer();
        serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
        serializer.transform(domSource, streamResult);
        out.close();

        String result = new String(out.toByteArray());
        System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Is this copied-verbatim  from the duplicate ?

Comment: It return html values but the style are comes as class instead of how can i get the style with in tag like this(<img width="10" style="something">) .

Comment: how to get the image tags and images