# How to download a doc file using struts 2.x

Tags: java, struts2

I have a requirement that I have to download a `.doc` file from database and show to the user.

So I am using struts 2.x and SQL server as my database.

So the user enters a password, the user can able to see his doc file which was fetched from the database.

Please can you provide me a sample example for the above requirement.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read the [faq] and [ask]. On SO we do not magically provide solutions to large problems like this.  You are expected to do your own work and ask **specific** questions.

Comment: @user1216228:how you want to show the .doc file? you want to show it on jsp page or you want other way? Please specify

Comment: hello Umesh.I want to show that .doc file in a JSP page . please can you a give a good example code for the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to show DOC file as html, please refer to this thread:

[Convert Word doc to HTML programmatically in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227236/convert-word-doc-to-html-programmatically-in-java)

Or if you're trying to generate DOC file from database, I would recommend [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) tool. The basic operation is, you should have your own DOC template file, and you can change and add values from JAVA file.

Also you can use reporting tools such as: [JasperReport](http://jasperforge.org/about/join), [Birt](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/) and [XDocReport](http://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/wiki/DocxReportingStruts2). But I am not sure about the last one. The things is, it is difficult to generate well-formed DOCs when using report tools.

Hope this helps.

Comment: you covered almost all aspects :)