# how to read .doc, .docx, .xls files in android

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-generation, converters, .doc

I am trying to show the PDF & .DOC files in android. I am able to show PDF files, but I have problem to show `the .DOC, .DOCX, .PPT and .xls files`.  With the help of **`WORD-EXTRACTOR`** we can fetch the text of the doc file but the problem is it only gives text not images from .doc file.

I searched to convert the doc file to PDF file but didn't succeed. Is it possible to convert the .doc files to PDF on device ?

If we want to show the .doc or .docx document in the android devices so which library is useful to do so? Any suggestions?

Comment: in theory this is possible but I don't know of any library to do this on android.

Comment: i searched & i found that it can fetch the data from doc n can create pdf using wordextractor but it looks like it is paragraph..

Comment: word-extractor is not made for what you want...

Comment: ya i read its specification...
it gives us all the text from the file.....

which is better.
1. to convert .doc to pdf or
2. to render .doc file seprately..????

Comment: cant you use java libraries? http://www.vogella.de/blog/2010/02/11/java-library-jar-android/

Comment: can you do this converting via a web service ?

Comment: but i want to make it on device..
if it is with web service it takes too much time to send the file & retrive...
if it is on device that would be much better...

Comment: i suggest you change name of this question to "how to render" or "how to display"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i suggest you  do

```
doc to html
html to pdf
```

[Convert Word doc to HTML programmatically in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227236/convert-word-doc-to-html-programmatically-in-java)

theres no successful pure java "doc to pdf" but there are good "doc to html"  and "html to pdf" ones